# Render some basic data using underscore templates

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, parse-platform

I am trying to render some basic data using underscore templates.
The data is returned in this format;

```
"[{"content":"Some Man Utd fans are beginning to doubt if manager, David Moyes is capable of handling the team","headline":"Man Utd are in shambles","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T04:21:00.264Z"},"objectId":"6GuLfFlCao","createdAt":"2014-02-10T04:21:05.633Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:18.138Z"},{"content":"Soccer fans all over the world are anticipating a mouth watering encounter","headline":"League leaders Arsenal face Liverpool at Anfield","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T04:21:00.273Z"},"objectId":"cPQd16yv2T","createdAt":"2014-02-10T04:21:06.248Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:20.733Z"},{"content":"Some Man Utd fans are beginning to doubt if manager, David Moyes is capable of handling the team","headline":"Man Utd are in shambles","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T09:25:21.534Z"},"objectId":"86vcmLYh0y","createdAt":"2014-02-10T09:25:46.689Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:27.454Z"},{"content":"Soccer fans all over the world are anticipating a mouth watering encounter","headline":"League leaders Arsenal face Liverpool at Anfield","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T09:25:21.541Z"},"objectId":"6TshHmMagv","createdAt":"2014-02-10T09:25:46.747Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:34.138Z"},{"content":"The gunner retain top position after Chelsea beat Man City at the Etihad","headline":"Arsenal retain top position","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T04:21:00.231Z"},"objectId":"l2r5fACLGf","createdAt":"2014-02-10T04:21:02.521Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:13.398Z"},{"content":"The gunner retain top position after Chelsea beat Man City at the Etihad","headline":"Arsenal retain top position","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T09:25:21.498Z"},"objectId":"JAR9JkUqjR","createdAt":"2014-02-10T09:25:44.086Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:25.314Z"},{"content":"What a great victory for the blues against a team that has scored and average 3 goal per game this season","headline":"Man City 0 - 1 Chelsea","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T04:21:00.254Z"},"objectId":"eRnVKhKW4H","createdAt":"2014-02-10T04:21:05.255Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:15.774Z"},{"content":"What a great victory for the blues against a team that has scored and average 3 goal per game this season","headline":"Man City 0 - 1 Chelsea","pictures":"empty","videos":"empty","date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-10T09:25:21.524Z"},"objectId":"GOkPkeFlQU","createdAt":"2014-02-10T09:25:42.308Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-17T19:10:23.733Z"}]"
```

This data is returned from a collection of NewsList on Parse.com.

```
var NewsList = Parse.collection.extend({
model:News
});
var newsList = new NewsList();
newsList.fetch({
success:function(newsList){
//successfully retrieved array of objects..
},
error:function(error){

}
});
```

I have tried to do this.

```
var template = _.template($("#news-template").html());
$("body").append(template(newsList))
```

My template looks like this;

```
<script type="text/template" id="news-template">
   <div id="newspaper">
   <% _.each(newsList, function(bulletin){ %>
   <div id="headline">
<%= headline %>
 </div>

 <div id="pictures">
 <%= pictures %>
 </div>

  <div id="videos">
 <%= videos %>
 </div>

  <div id="content">
 <%= content %>
 </div>

 <% }); %>

 </div>
</script>
```

I get reference error headline is undefined when i run this code. Please help I've been on this for days now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code:

1. You try to access the array you are passing to your template as `newsList`. For this you have to pass it as value for the key newsList into the template
2. You try to access the properties of your `newsList` array items by their key only - you'll have to access them trough `bulletin` which holds the item data in your `_.each` loop

You'd have to do this:

Javascript:

```
$("body").append(template({ newsList: newsList }));
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="news-template">
<div id="newspaper">
 <% _.each(newsList, function(bulletin){ %>
    <div id="headline">
       <%= bulletin.headline %>
    </div>

    <div id="pictures">
      <%= bulletin.pictures %>
    </div>

    <div id="videos">
      <%= bulletin.videos %>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <%= bulletin.content %>
    </div>

  <% }); %>
</div>
</script>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/S2rUp/

Comment: After trying out this solution I still cant get it to work. I get the error TypeError: bulletin is undefined. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with a Fiddle, perhaps it helps with making things clear.

Comment: This time no error is returned but page is just simply empty. What I changed was to assign the returned data to a variable and pass this variable into the template with newsList as described in the fiddle. The returned data is supposed to be key value pairs and the key should probably not be a string, but the fiddle proves me wrong there as string keys and values still produce results.  Thanks so much for your efforts.